# Export test lists in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have an application for which I am maintaining multiple versions. So, for that I have multiple versions of solution. I created test lists to group some unit test cases in one solution. Now, I have to do the same in another solution. Is there any way we can export the tests list and include them in another solution.
Both solutions have same unit test cases.

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to copy the VSDMI file (containing the test lists) from the one solution to the other. Since it references the same unittest, I expect it to just work.

Another approach would be to get rid of your test lists and categorize your unittests. The categories are registered as attributes with the tests, so in any solution, you can re-use the test categories to group (much more flexible than test lists) test for execution. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx for details on using test categories.